# get an id from a new insert php sql

Tags: php, sql, unique, increment

I make an insert in my database and after this insert i want to get my id ( but he is auto increment ) and all the data i have on this one are not unique . I want create a folder with this id.

```
$reponse = $bdd->prepare(' INSERT INTO motorbike (countryMotorbike,idModel,idGarage) VALUES (?,?,?) ');
    $reponse->execute(array($country,$modelid,$_SESSION['idgarage']));


    mkdir('./photos_customer/'.$_SESSION['id'].', 0777, true);
```

I can make a select with all the params i give to create this " motorbike " but if an other one has the same params it's could fail. That's why i need to get my ID but i really don't know how to do it.

Thank you for your help.

And sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I believe you can just do `$bdd->insert_id` after the insert if you are using mysqli, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: look for sql server http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the last inserted id from [the `lastInsertId` function](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php).  Something like this:

```
$reponse = $bdd->prepare(' INSERT INTO motorbike (countryMotorbike,idModel,idGarage) VALUES (?,?,?) ');
$reponse->execute(array($country,$modelid,$_SESSION['idgarage']));

$id = $response->lastInsertId();
```